# Having trouble with CakePHP 2.0 admin prefix and AuthComponent within my plugin on User model specifically

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, authentication, cakephp-2.0

```
public function admin_view($user_id = NULL) {
    debug($this->User); exit;
}

public function view($user_id = null) {
    debug($this->User); exit;
}
```

This is within my plugin's UsersController. admin_view instantiates an AppModel object while view() instantiates the correct UserModel/PluginNameAppModel. This is only doing this to my User model which is tied into ACL as well as my Group model, which this isn't happening to. Worked fine before converting to a plugin. Still doesn't work with a fresh-baked plugin model. Doesn't work when the entire User model is commented out, either. The admin prefix line from app/Config/core.php is commented out, enabled admin prefixes. There is no routing within the plugin's folder. When I use this line:

```
$this->Auth->allow('admin_index');
```

It instantiates the correct model so this is likely an AuthComponent issue.

This was using CakePHP 2.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an AclNode defect set to be fixed on 2.0.6.